# Validation in AJAX Form Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, validation

I've made a form in Ci which submits the data to the Db. I've been trying to implement validation in the form, For eg Name : more than 3+ Letters, email '@' Etc.

I never could seem to make it work, tried using Jquery validation with different sources , the form basically submits without Validation, Any pointers to where i'm going wrong?

The code below is just a snippet without any validation codes attached to it.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquire">Enquire</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="enquire">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enquire About "<?php echo $row_company->company_name; ?> "</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="reg_form" id="reg_form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('name')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label class="input-group">Your Name <span>*</span></label>
                            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required="required" data-error="Name is required." maxlength="40">
                            <?php echo form_error('name'); ?> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('email')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label class="input-group">Email <span>*</span></label>
                            <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Valid Email Id" required="required" maxlength="50">
                            <?php echo form_error('email'); ?> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('mobile')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label class="input-group">Mobile Number <span>*</span></label>
                            <input name="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required="required" maxlength="50">
                            <?php echo form_error('mobile'); ?> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="college" value='<?php echo $row_company->company_name; ?>'>
                    <p> <input id="click_form" value="submit" type="button" ></p>
                </form>
                <div class="ajax_success"></div>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#click_form').click(function () {
                            var url = "<?php echo site_url('enquiry/ajax_post_form') ?>";
                            var data = $("#reg_form").serialize();
                            $.post(url, data, function (data) {
                                $('.ajax_success').html('Enquiry Submitted Successfully!');
                            }, "json");

                        });
                    });

                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function ajax_post_form() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Your name', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags');

    $user_data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
        'college' => $this->input->post('college')
    );

    $this->insert_model->form_insert($user_data);
    $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
    echo json_encode($user_data);
}
```

**Model**

```
function form_insert($user_data){
    $this->db->insert('pp_enquiry', $user_data);
}
```

**Validation **

```
    function checkForm() {
// Fetching values from all input fields and storing them in variables.
var name = document.getElementById("username1").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email1").value;
var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
//Check input Fields Should not be blanks.
if (name == '' ||  email == '' || mobile == '') {
alert("Fill All Fields");
} else {
//Notifying error fields
var username1 = document.getElementById("username");
var email1 = document.getElementById("email");
var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
//Check All Values/Informations Filled by User are Valid Or Not.If All Fields Are invalid Then Generate alert.
if (username1.innerHTML == 'Must be 3+ letters' || email1.innerHTML == 'Invalid email' || mobile.innerHTML == 'Invalid website') {
alert("Fill Valid Information");
} else {
//Submit Form When All values are valid.
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
}
}
// AJAX code to check input field values when onblur event triggerd.
function validate(field, query) {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
} else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
} else {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occurred. <a href='index.php'>Reload Or Try Again</a> the page.";
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "validation.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Where is jquery form validation code ? and where are the rules you mentioned `For eg Name : more than 3+ Letters, email '@' Etc` ?

Comment: Added with the Edit @HimanshuUpadhyay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check here is the working example of your above code. I think you missed something in your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 25},
            email: {required: true, email: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 100, regex: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+/},
            mobile: {required: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 12, number: true}
        },
        messages: {
            email: {required: "Please enter valid Email Address"},
            mobile: {required: "Please provide valid Phone or Mobile number!"}
        }
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
        if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
            regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
        else if (regexp.global)
            regexp.lastIndex = 0;
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    }, "Please provide valid email address.");

    $('#click_form').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $valid = $("#reg_form").valid();
        if (!$valid) {
            $validator.focusInvalid();
            return false;
        } else {
            var url = 'https://www.example.com';
            var data = $("#reg_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                success: function(returnData) {
                    if (returnData.status) {
                        $('.ajax_success').html('Enquiry Submitted Successfully!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquire">Enquire</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="enquire">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enquire About "Company Name"</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="reg_form" id="reg_form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('name')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label class="input-group">Your Name <span>*</span></label>
                            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required="required" data-error="Name is required." maxlength="40">
                            <?php echo form_error('name'); ?> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('email')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label class="input-group">Email <span>*</span></label>
                            <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Valid Email Id" required="required" maxlength="50">
                            <?php echo form_error('email'); ?> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group <?php echo (form_error('mobile')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label class="input-group">Mobile Number <span>*</span></label>
                            <input name="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required="required" maxlength="50">
                            <?php echo form_error('mobile'); ?> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="college" value='<?php echo $row_company->company_name; ?>'>
                    <p> <input id="click_form" value="submit" type="button" ></p>
                </form>
                <div class="ajax_success"></div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shyam , This solutions works like a charm! Thank you so much!, and I realized that I was making things worse by calling Jquery and validation twice.

Comment: However, I tried replacing the url in AJAX form with the original one, Validation works , but the form does not submit, its just a dead click. Chrome XHR shows all 4 fields with the input data.

Comment: Whats your original URL.?

Comment: controller call :  var url = "<?php echo site_url('enquiry/ajax_post_form') ?>";

Comment: var sendUrl = '<?= base_url('enquiry/ajax_post_form') ?>';

Comment: Have you added `base_url` in `config/config.php`..?

Comment: Currently my base url is empty

Comment: Then please set `base_url` in `config/config.php`.

Comment: I did Shyam, changed it to $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/jobportal/'; Still persists, Sorry if this is getting annoying, I really appreciate all your help on this, means a lot!

Comment: You have to add `http://localhost/jobportal` as base url, and in `config/autoload.php` file  `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'common');` this lines needs to add

Comment: in autoload those above mentioned lines were already there with a bunch of few others, except for common.

Comment: Lets add `http://localhost/jobportal/enquiry/ajax_post_form` in ajax URL so you will come to know that error is because of `site_url()` or `base_url()` function.

Comment: You're right, I used the base_url() instead of site_url(), now it works. Sorted out things in config.php too. Thank you so much Shyam!

Answer (score 0):

You can find below mentioned solution.

> **PHP Validation**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Your name', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags|min_length[3]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags|valid_email|min_length[3]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|strip_all_tags|min_length[10]|max_length[12]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $data['status'] = false;
    $data['error'] = validation_errors();
} else {
    $user_data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
        'college' => $this->input->post('college')
    );
    $this->insert_model->form_insert($user_data);
    $data['status'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

> **jQuery Validation**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 25},
            email: {required: true, email: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 100, regex: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+/},
            mobile: {required: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 12, number: true}
        },
        messages: {
            email: {required: "Please enter valid Email Address"},
            mobile: {required: "Please provide valid Phone or Mobile number!"}
        }
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
        if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
            regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
        else if (regexp.global)
            regexp.lastIndex = 0;
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    }, "Please provide valid email address.");

    $('#click_form').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $valid = $("#reg_form").valid();
        if (!$valid) {
            $validator.focusInvalid();
            return false;
        } else {
            var url = '<?php echo site_url('enquiry/ajax_post_form') ?>';
            var data = $("#reg_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // Code if required before Send
                },
                success: function(returnData) {
                    if (returnData.status) {
                        $('.ajax_success').html('Enquiry Submitted Successfully!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: I managed to merge this code, this looks very promising but when i try inserting into the fields , it doesn't validate, not does it send the request. It just stays there after i press submit , No post success message too.

Comment: @ZeehanAkhtarMohammed : Please check my updated answer, And let me know if you have any error

Comment: Same Issue Shyam, is there any way to debug from chrome to see what happens when the submit button is clicked, cause my Chrome console is blank

Comment: Can you check in Chrome network, in Network tab you will get actual ajax request and response

Comment: Thank you for pointing put on the chrome network tab and XHR. Took a HAR report of it, http://lpaste.net/8790746372040032256

seems like the values of name, email, mobile don't get parsed when being posted, any idea why?

Comment: As per above link your post data is passing variables but values are empty in `postData`.

Comment: Please check my another answer, I have added working example of your above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the validation process as explained in the manual: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
```

Comment: Added this Validation Process , and went through CI Documentation too, it didn't work out, Is it because i use onClick instead of submit?